# How to disable a CSS style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm currently using the `antd` package with my React App including the CSS package. However, I'd like to disable a rule:

```
body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
```

How would I disable/remove this rule without not importing the CSS?

Comment: could just import another css file after the antd css and overide the width and height with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite that rule importing your personal CSS  after package CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access that CSS for whatever reason, you can add your own CSS like so;

```
body, html {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Example:

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

body {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  The body background colour should be BLUE as per CSS, but because of the following INHERIT attribute, it is now back to default white.
</div>
```

You can read more about the `inherit` attribute here;

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
body, html {
      //  width: 100%;
      //  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Haha! I think we're assuming they don't have access to the CSS. Question is kinda vague and not specific on the issue. I'll laugh if this is all it is.

Comment: You wanna bet? LOL

Comment: I'm worried I'm gonna lose!! HAHA!